# How to show WorldOrigin axis in SceneKit scene for macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui, scenekit

I am building a macOS SwiftUI app. I want to show the world axis such that the user is aware of the orientation of objects. I've looked at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scndebugoptions/2882039-showworldorigin), but the `showWorldOrigin` debug setting is not available on `macOS`. Is there an alternative way to show the world axis that I am missing?

While I've found [external libraries](https://gist.github.com/cenkbilgen/ba5da0b80f10dc69c10ee59d4ccbbda6) that create a world axis and add nodes to the scene, I was hoping there was a built-in method to simplify the task and reduce any error.

Comment: On iOS, `.showWorldOrigin` is also not defined... this worked for me though: `.debugOptions = SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 2048)`

Comment: @DonMag you should add that as an answer, as it is better than the ones found so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this answer, as per OP comments...

Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scndebugoptions) list the following `SCNDebugOptions`:

```
.showPhysicsShapes
.showBoundingBoxes
.showLightInfluences
.showLightExtents
.showPhysicsFields
.showWireframe
.renderAsWireframe
.showSkeletons
.showCreases
.showConstraints
.showCameras
.showFeaturePoints
.showWorldOrigin
```

Curiously, the last two - `.showFeaturePoints` and `.showWorldOrigin` - are not defined in SceneKit. And the discussion notes refer only to ARKit, where they *are* defined.

The docs for `SCNDebugOptions` state that these are `bit mask patterns` ... and if we print them out, we get:

```
showPhysicsShapes:   SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 1)
showBoundingBoxes:   SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 2)
showLightInfluences: SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 4)
showLightExtents:    SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 8)
showPhysicsFields:   SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 16)
showWireframe:       SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 32)
renderAsWireframe:   SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 64)
showSkeletons:       SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 128)
showCreases:         SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 256)
showConstraints:     SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 512)
showCameras:         SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 1024)
```

So... we try this to get "the next one in order" (expecting it to equate to `.showFeaturePoints`):

```
sceneView.debugOptions = SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 2048)
```

Turns out, that gives us RGB axis indicators ... the `.showWorldOrigin`.

For a simple scene with an extruded bezier path (a cube), using these options:

```
sceneView.debugOptions = [.renderAsWireframe, SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 2048)]
```

we get this output:

[image]

Trying one further, thinking maybe we get `.showFeaturePoints`:

```
sceneView.debugOptions = SCNDebugOptions(rawValue: 4096)
```

doesn't seem to do anything - at least, I don't see any visual change in my simple Scene.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own sample of procedural world axis for macOS 3D app.

[image]

### SwiftUI mac version

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentView : View {
    
    @State private var scene = SCNScene()
    @State private var axis = SCNNode()
    var options: SceneView.Options = [.allowsCameraControl]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SceneView(scene: scene, options: options).ignoresSafeArea()
            let _ = scene.background.contents = NSColor.black
            let _ = createWorldAxis()
            let _ = axis.opacity = 0.1          // you can hide world axis
        }
    }
    
    func createWorldAxis() {
            
        let colors: [NSColor] = [.systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue]

        for index in 0...2 {
            
            let box = SCNBox(width: 0.200, height: 0.005,
                            length: 0.005, chamferRadius: 0.001)
            
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.lightingModel = .constant
            material.diffuse.contents = colors[index]
            box.materials[0] = material
            
            let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)
            
            switch index {
                case 0:
                    node.position.x += 0.1
                case 1:
                    node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, 0, Float.pi/2)
                    node.position.y += 0.1
                case 2:
                    node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, -Float.pi/2, 0)
                    node.position.z += 0.1
                default: break
            }    
            axis.addChildNode(node)
            axis.scale = SCNVector3(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(axis)                
        }
        print(axis.position)
    }
}
```

### Cocoa version

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit

class ViewController : NSViewController {
    
    var axis = SCNNode()
    var sceneView = SCNView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .black
      
        self.createWorldAxis()
        axis.opacity = 0.1                     // you can hide world axis
    }
    
    func createWorldAxis() {
        
        let colors: [NSColor] = [.systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue]

        for index in 0...2 {
            
            let box = SCNBox(width: 0.200, height: 0.005, 
                            length: 0.005, chamferRadius: 0.001)
            
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.lightingModel = .constant
            material.diffuse.contents = colors[index]
            box.materials[0] = material
            
            let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)

            if index == 0 {
                node.position.x += 0.1    
            } else if index == 1 {
                node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, 0, Float.pi/2)
                node.position.y += 0.1    
            } else if index == 2 {
                node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, -Float.pi/2, 0)
                node.position.z += 0.1
            }
            axis.addChildNode(node)
            axis.scale = SCNVector3(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)
            sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(axis)                
        }
        print(axis.position)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found what i wanted using the UI. First, ensure you enable controls for your scene:

```
myscene.showsStatistics = true
```

Then, click the configuration button on the bottom of your screen.

[image]

In the options dropdown select World Origin.

[image]

I am puzzled why all debug options can be invoked programmatically except the World Origin. None the less, that allows you to see axis.